# Update last child in Firebase list

Tags: javascript, firebase

Documentation in Firebase JS SDK is a bit obscure, but from what I gather, if I want to update the last item of a list, I have to ref the list like this and chain to update?

```
const { uid } = await firebase.auth().currentUser;

const ref = firebase
    .app()
    .database()
    .ref();

const userRef = ref
    .child('users/' + uid + '/myList')
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(1)
    .update({ stamp: Date.now() });
```

But no dice.

```
// TypeError: ref.child(...).orderByKey(...).limitToLast(...).update is not a function
```

Update:

I can clearly see the correct toString value of my ref, but value is non-existent in a snap?

```
const { uid } = await firebase.auth().currentUser;

const ref = firebase
    .database()
    .ref('users/' + uid)
    .child('myList');

console.log(ref.toString()); // firebaseio.com/users/XtNjKhhF...lfBn2/myList

ref.on('value', function(snap) {
    console.log('snap val', snap.val()); // never called
});

// data is clearly there, no?
{
  "users" : {
    "Xt....lfABn2" : {
      "myList" : {
        "-LZDd5G2lhNv5ogv" : {
          "start" : 1550728848450
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no dice"?  What's the problem here?

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=no%20dice

Comment: That last comment made me lol. I don't think @DougStevenson was actually asking what *No Dice* means - he was asking what the actual issue us. The error message in the question is pretty clear: .update is not a function for that call so you're calling something that doesn't exist. The documentation provides a couple of specific examples of how to update a field - take a look at [Update Specific Fields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields). Read through that and update your code so it contains legal API calls and let us know where you're stuck.

Comment: Thanks @Jay, yeah I figured that TypeError would suffice as in, "why the type error, does anybody know the right way to do this?" ;). I don't see anything in the documentation to do something like this without a previous reference to the created object.  I think its pretty clear what I'm trying to do, right?  The missing context, however might be that I'm trying todo an independent operation with no previous reference of whats in the list.  I just know the list exists and want to update the last item only.  Thanks for the help.  Totally stuck here and I know I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: With firebase, if you want to update anything you need to a) explicitly know the 'path' to the node, or b) retrieve that path via an observe or query. So for a) if you want to update the last post in a list of posts, `var lastPost = firebase.database().ref('posts').limitToLast(1);` - that post will be returned in a snapshot so you know the key and can then update whatever child values you want, via a ref to that node. So bottom line is that you need to update the *ref*, not the snapshot returned from a query. Make sense?

Comment: @Jay loosing my mind.  This should be so easy, right?  Even my ref callback is not called on 'value'.  Data seems to be there, made an update above.

Answer (score 1):

This code returns a snapshot, but you are treating it as a ref

```
const userRef = ref
    .child('users/' + uid + '/myList')
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(1)
```

You can't do the update() on a snapshot

```
  .update({ stamp: Date.now() });
```

That is why you need to add `.ref` to the snaptshot

```
const userRef = ref
    .child('users/' + uid + '/myList')
    .orderByKey()
    .limitToLast(1)
    .ref                            // <- this line here
    .update({ stamp: Date.now() });
```

Comment: no error, just silently does its thing and the database is not updated.

Comment: can you check if the stamp was added to the parent as a new child instead? We might need to pass the child name before the update